# An interesting renumber combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $M$ different integers $1,...,M$ and a sequence of these $M$ integers of length $N$, in which the counts of each integer are $k_1,k_2,...,k_M$. Apparently $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{k_i}}  = N$. For example, a sequence $2,2,3,1,1,3,3$ consists of $7$ integers of three $3$ kinds $1,2,3$, thus we have $M=3,k_1=2,k_2=2,k_3=3,N=7$.

Now we perform some renumbering according to occurrence order. The first kind of integer that occurs in the sequence is re-numbered as $1$, and the second kind of integer that occurs in the sequence is re-numbered as $2$, etc. Take the above example, "$2$" occurs first in the sequence and is re-numbered as $1$, "$3$" occurs secondly in the sequence and is re-numbered as $2$, and "$1$" is re-numbered as $3$ for it is the last kind of integer that occurs in the sequence. The re-numbered sequence is $1,1,2,3,3,2,2$.

In the re-numbered sequence there are still $M$ kinds of integers $1,...,M$ and record the counts of each integer as $n_1,n_2,...,n_M$. They can be different from $k_1,k_2,...,k_M$ but still sum to $N$. In the above example, $n_1=2,n_2=3,n_3=2$.

**The question is**, given such length-$N$ sequence of $M$ different integers, how many different sequences are possible after the re-numbering? $n_1,...,n_M$ are also known quantities, but $k_1,...,k_M$ are unknown so they cannot be used in calculation. **The result should be an expression of variables** $M,N,n_1,...,n_m$.

I have verified that for $M=3,N=7,n_1=2,n_2=3,n_3=2$ there are 36 such possible re-numbered sequences. Hope someone can help with a general solution. Thank you.